# Does $P(X\leq a) = P(X^2\leq a^2)$ if $X$ is a positive random variable and $a>0$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The answer looks positive to me, since $$P(\omega:X(\omega) \leq a) = P(\omega:X(\omega)^2\leq a^2)$$
Am I right?

Comment: yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X(\omega) > 0$ for all $\omega$, and $a>0$, then
$$
    X(\omega)^2 \leq a^2 \iff X(\omega) \leq a
$$
So as sets,
$$
    \{\omega : X(\omega)^2 \leq a^2\} = \{\omega :  X(\omega) \leq a\}
$$